# Techniques and terminology for learning a massive code base

Tags: generics, programming-languages

This question is not specific to one programming language in particular, and perhaps intended to help someone who isn't formally trained in programming.

I have always worked on my own and without any collaborators. It has meant that I've never had to learn the source of a code base written by someone else. I can imagine this is a typical problem and several techniques and tools exist to get an overview of code for each language, and also to learn the details of them. I don't know these strategies, but I need to use them now, it seems. I wouldn't be surprised if there are already interactive tools for various languages that can help someone to learn a big code.

I'm from a different field, and now I am working with engineers that have a big code written in some foreign language (Julia language, that I have a beginning knowledge of). They are 10 or so people, and have been writing up this code base for 5 or so years. I don't know how to find out how many lines it is, because there are so many files, but it's 30 MB of text files and I cannot get them to teach me anything because they are all so busy on their parts and there isn't a culture to teach anyone any new tricks. I only have a number of compiled examples of the code that demonstrates what the code can do, and the source itself and now I am expected to fix broken things in the code and later add to it. There is no documentation and no comments to speak of. But I understand the mathematical method that the code base implements, and therefore I have some sense of what to expect that a function or data type does based on the names. But I have a big problem because I use hours to navigate to stitch it together without feeling that I am getting anywhere because it is so big for me. I use `grep` and `less` to track things down and try to draw diagrams on A4-paper.

Could you please explain, in a language-non-specific-way (using the right terminology), which tools exist and how/what I may use them for? Don't assume I know anything of what you learned in programming-school or in the workplace because I am 100% self-taught and had no friends that knew programming. Here are some questions that I have to find (preferably) multiple answers to:

- If a function calls a number of other functions, which way can I piece together what it does? In particular when there are a dozen different definition of each function (because there are different input types) scattered all over the place.
- If I don't understand the types, and which inherits from what, how can I quickly get an overview of the hierarchy?
- If I know the input type to a function, how can I narrow down the possible definitions that might be called at runtime? Often I don't know which function is applicable because the function isn't defined for the type that I have, but it is defined of a supertype.
- Did I forget to mention any problems that have solutions that I will need?

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?